# Plot f[2x] with ScalingFunctions

Tags: plotting

I have trouble  upscaling function f[x]

```
f[x_] := 0 /; x < 0;
f[x_] := 1 /; 0 <= x < 1;
f[x_] := 0 /; 1 <= x;
Plot[Piecewise[{{f[x], x < 0}, {f[x], 0 <= x < 1}, {f[x], 
    1 < x}}], {x, -5, 5}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotRange -> 5 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, PlotStyle -> {Pink, Thick}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> "2" ]
```

**How to Plot f[2x]**

What's wrong with this?

Comment: Try `ScalingFunctions ->{Function[x,2*x],Function[x,x/2]}` which I get from looking at the documentation https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingFunctions.html and clicking on the orange Details. That makes me guess that you cannot just put any constant in quotes and expect that to be understood to multiply your plot by that constant. Try changing the 2 to 4 or to 1 in my example and see if your plot changes correctly

Comment: @Bill why should I add `Function[x,x/2]`?

Comment: I'm happy it is working for you. I only guessed what to try after reading the documentation.

Comment: @Bill, Sorry for my carelessness, yours is not not working after a full check. The domain has been changed when you  upscale this by 2.  `0 <= x < 1/2; 1/2<=x`